# Standard prelude name for fmap . const

Tags: function, haskell, functor, built-in

The composition  `fmap . const` is a function that takes some constant and a set of elements and returns a set of elements in which all the elements in set are replaced with the constant.

For example, `(fmap . const) 5 [1,2,7]` returns `[5,5,5]`.

Is there any standard prelude function that does exactly that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for [`(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36-).